# Multi page form

Tags: orbeon

How can I create a multi page form in [Orbeon Form Builder](http://www.orbeon.com/forms/orbeon-form-builder)? I want the next page to be determined based on the answers of the earlier questions. Please point me to any documentation in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See *[Create a wizard or multi-page form with Form Builder](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/fb-fr/form-builder-wizard)*.